# How to load external javascript file into Robomongo UI?

Tags: robo3t

I want to load **lodash** while db scripting in RoboMongo's shell.

I've tried doing `load('lodash.min.js')` in my db script, but the shell doesn't see the library. The db script and the library are in the same directory.

Answer (score 3):

What I did as a workaround for now, was to set the absolute path for loading the library.

`load('/absolute/path/to/the/library/');`

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the current directory of the shell just run **`pwd()`** on the robo3t Shell

And use the path to place your external script, this will let you just put the script file name in the **`load('script.js')`** instead of the entire absolute path.